# Execute SQLite SELECT substituting both integers and a variable list of strings?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to select a sequence of 10 books, each by a different author.

So I get a result, add its author to the authors_done list, and try to get another:

```
authors_done = []
for x in range(10):
    db_cursor.execute('SELECT title, author FROM books WHERE (year between ? and ?) and (country = ?) and (author not in (?)) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1', (min_year, max_year, country, ','.join(authors_done)))
    curtitle, curauthor = db_cursor.fetchone()
    authors_done.append(curauthor)
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm getting duplicate authors, instead of 10 different authors.

I have a feeling I should be using executemany and f strings, but I can't figure out how to make that work.

P.S. On second thought, would it make more sense to get a distinct list of authors, then loop through that and get a random book per author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking for 10 things, and looking at the first, throwing away the other 9, and then doing all that again, 9 more times. Your `author not in` check does nothing because it's expecting an array not a string. And anyway, you can do this whole thing in SQL.

```sql
SELECT 
  title, author 
FROM books 
WHERE 
  (year BETWEEN ? AND ?)
  AND (country = ?)
```

This will get all `(title, author)` pairs. You can add `LIMIT 10` if there are more than 10 things, and you only want the first 10.

Then use:

```py
title_authors = db_cursor.fetchall()
```

---

If it's actually that each author might have more than one book, but you only want to get each author, and a random title, you can do:

```sql
SELECT
  title, author
FROM books
WHERE
  (year BETWEEN ? AND ?)
  AND (country = ?)
GROUP BY author
```

And if there are actually more than 10 authors, and you only want 10, you can add `LIMIT 10` to that statement.

---

In response to your comment, I think that's more tricky. It is possible to do in SQL, but only with a subquery IIRC. I believe there's another SO post about it, but I can't find it. Given you have Python available, I think it would be easier to handle it there.

Something like?

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict

db_cursor.execute("""
SELECT title, author
FROM books 
WHERE (year BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND country = ? 
""", (min_year, max_year, country))

books = db_cursor.fetchall()  # this is all pairs (title, author)

author_books = defaultdict(list)  # this will be author => all titles
for title, author in books:
    author_books[author].append(title)

selection = [
   (random.choice(all_titles), author)
   for author, all_titles in author_books.items()
]  # back to (title, author) pairs
```

If you actually do want pure SQL, it's

```
WITH all_titles AS (
    SELECT title, author 
    FROM books 
    WHERE (year BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (country = ?)
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
) SELECT 
    title, author
FROM all_titles
GROUP BY author
```

This is because you can't put an `ORDER BY` statement before `GROUP BY`, so you have to jump through hoops to do that.

Comment: Thank you, blueteeth - that is a MUCH better approach. However, I'm currently getting the same book every time for a particular author, rather than a different random book. My code is    SELECT title, author FROM books WHERE (year between ? and ?) and (country = ?) group by author  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10   but I get the same book whenever an author comes up - I want a random book each time, so "Dickens" might have "Great Expectations" one time and "A Christmas Carol" another. Can I do that?

Comment: @KristiWachter I've updated my post. Some hoop jumping is involved to do it in pure SQL.

Comment: Thank you, blueteeth! That pure SQL approach works perfectly - and it's really nice to have both options, sqlite only or python plus SQL. Thanks for both solving my problem and helping me learn more ways to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to pick just 1 random `title` for each author and then pick `10` random `author`s:

```
SELECT title, author
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY author ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn
  FROM books 
  WHERE (year BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (country = ?) AND (author NOT IN (?)) 
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```